# Why V-Dialog wont show up?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to figure out why the V-Dialog wont popout and when im trying to click the button, the v-dialog should pop out but it didnt, and this is the error i got

```
[object Error]: 
{description: "'ShadowRoot' is not defined", 
message: "'ShadowRoot' is not defined", 
number: -2146823279, 
stack: "ReferenceError: 'ShadowRoot' is not defined at 
handleShadow (eval code:33314:3) at 
inserted (eval code:33334:5) at 
callHook$1 (eval code:6714:7) at 
callInsert (eval code:6653:9) at 
wrappedHook (eval code:2243:5) at 
invokeWithErrorHandling (eval code:1862:5) at 
invoker (eval code:2183:9) at 
invokeInsertHook (eval code:6380:9) at 
patch (eval code:6599:5) at 
Vue.prototype._update (eval code:3957:7)"}
```

and here are the code :
html

```
<div>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="data"
        class="elevation-1"
        hide-default-footer
      >

        <template v-slot:[`item.action`]="{ item }">
          <v-btn depressed @click="view(item.book_id)" color="primary">View</v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <v-text-field v-model="ItemPerPage" label="Items Per Page" @change="GettingDataPerItem"> 
        </v-text-field>
    </div>

    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="800px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="subtitle-1 font-weight-bold">Details Of Book</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-form lazy-validation>
          <v-col cols="12" align-self="center">
            <v-layout wrap justify-center>
              <v-flex d-flex lg5 sm5 xs12>
                <v-text-field v-model="book_id" :readonly="true" class="allText" label="Book ID"/>
              </v-flex>
              <v-divider class="mx-4" vertical/>
            </v-layout>
          </v-col>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-layout v-if="IsActive === 0" justify-end class="ma-4">
              <div>
                <v-btn @click="dialog = false" style="width:150px;margin-left:10px" color="#263238" class="white--text">Close</v-btn>
              </div>
            </v-layout>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-form>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

When i read the code like over 20 times, it looks fine with me, and read the script over and over and nothing wrong to me

script

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      //censored_code
    };
  },
view(emp_no) {
      this.$axios
        .$post(`some/api/.......`, {
          book_id: book_id,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            //result of the respond data
            this.dialog = true
        });
    },
},
```

This ShadowRoot annoyed me, how to fix this? should upgrade something?

Comment: It looks like you're missing the methods() block around view(emp_no).

Comment: it just a piece of method that i paste, but i already wrap the view() method inside the method block

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `<v-data-table>` and `<v-dialog>` elements are contained within a single root:

```
<template>
  **<something>**
    <div><v-data-table></v-data-table></div>
    <v-dialog/>
  **</something>**
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve the problem, i'm using microsoft edge and then switch to firefox and the v-dialog poped out